# Download a file from a specific link and store it in device iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios6

I am currently working on a iOS application in which I show a download link to download a Excel sheet. I want to save that downloaded file to a location of my iOS device where all my downloaded applications are stored by default, so that I can access it later form my device without opening the application.

Like in android devices, files are stored in my files from where we can access them later on.

Is there any approach to achieve this in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can store directly on Document Directory as below

```
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tempfile"]]; // It may change according to your need

        NSError * error = nil;
        [imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

Here ,imageData is my data to be write on Document directory

And by saving on Document Directory you can get it from there

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * str = "Your Url"
 NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]
                                                      cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed
                                                  timeoutInterval:20];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;

        NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                              returningResponse:&response
                                                          error:&error];

            NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with it for once

```
// NSData downloads any file from an URL
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.8/PoweredByMacOSX.gif"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

// get the documents directory
NSArray* pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDir = documentsDirectory = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* localFile =
              [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"webfile.png"];

// write the downloaded file to documents dir
[data writeToFile:localFile atomically:YES];
```